# Who receives left value when calling function with value

Tags: solidity

I found code like below

[ContractA]

```
function something() {
    contractBAddr.doSomething{value: msg.value}();
}
```

[ContractB]

```
function doSomething() {
    uint amount = msg.value.sub(someAmount);
    _refundAddress.call{value: amount}(""); // Not all of value
    // where left value goes?
}
```

something function of ContractA is called. Then part of value are sent in doSomething of Contract B.
My question is where left value is gone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount would be on contract B.

You make a transaction with X amount, the function executes it self and the remaining stays on the contract B.

I hope this small explanation helps :)